# pip doesn't check installed packages

Tags: python, pip

When I use 'pip' to install packages, even if the package has already been installed, it will continue to install, instead of showing the prompt of 'Requirements already satisfied'.

But when I try to install with 'sudo pip', this prompt will come up and the package will not be installed.

I am not using any virtual environment, but the pip that comes with the ubuntu system. So how does pip check installed packages and how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: who says it is a problem? I believe pip updates existing packages to the newest vesions

Comment: I think it's a problem, since I have done an experiment by taking numpy installation as  an example:

1. Install numpy by using 'pip install numpy==1.16.4'
2. Install again with the same command as in 1, I didn't recieve any prompt.
3. Run command 'sudo pip isntall numpy==1.16.4', I recieved the prompt of requirements already satisfied.

Comment: Yeah sure it does that. But *why* is that a problem is what I'm not getting?

Comment: Because it caused a duplicated installation and we got an error when importing numpy.

Comment: Well you didn't mention that. You should also add in your post what the error says when importing.

Comment: Sorry about that, so can you help me with fixing this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Like I said. please edit your question so it includes the error. How do I know if I can help you if I don't know what it complains about?

Comment: After uninstalling and reinstalling pip the problem is solved. So there might be some conflict between two different pythons. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have a file `~/.pip/pip.conf`? Show its content, please.

Comment: No, I didn't find the .pip directory.